# How do I add --promote in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications, google-cloud-intellij

I am deploying my application to Google App Engine through IntelliJ plugin Cloud Code -> App Engine -> Deploy to App Engine. The application deploys just fine and the app works, just that it creates a different target-url than I have set while creating application:

it's supposed to be (e.g.): mynameoftheproject.appspot.com

and instead I'm getting something like this: https://20200131t170730-dot-mynameoftheproject.appspot.com]

Underneath I get information:

```
(add --promote if you also want to make this service available from
 [https://mynameoftheproject.appspot.com])
```

And since I'm not using the command line, how can I add this promote parameter into application configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this url https://20200131t170730-dot-mynameoftheproject.appspot.com, `20200131t170730` is a version ID. This lets you deploy a new version without sending traffic to it yet, so that you can try it out first.

You can manage the versions of your project here: https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions

If you just want to your new version to automatically become the primary version, go into settings and edit your deployment configuration and check the box for:
"Promote the deployed version to receive all traffic"

https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/deploy-std#deploy